# Getting "no main manifest attribute" for spring boot application when using docker compose

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker-compose

I am working on a simple scenario where i am launching a spring boot application and before that spinning off mysql container. I am doing this using docker-compose but i am getting `no main manifest attribute` error.
Following is my `pom.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.springlearn</groupId>
    <artifactId>learnspringdb</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>usermanagement</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <start-class>om.springlearn.learnspringdb.UsermanagementApplication</start-class>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

and below is the docker-compose file.

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    container_name: spring_boot_app
    build: ./
    ports:
     - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    environment:
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/user_management

  mysql:
    image: mysql:8.1.0
    ports:
      - "3307:3036"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_USER: root
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
```

I googled and made adjustments to pom.xml for this issue but still its not working.

if i launch spring boot application individually then it works fine but giving error in docker-compose only.

Any thoughts on what is missing here?

my github repo: https://github.com/algouser/learnspringdb

Comment: I followed your link: __1)__ I don't think that a `maven-assembly-plugin` is mandatory, `spring-boot-maven-plugin` is enough to handle things. Try to remove assembly plugin. __2)__ In your `@SpringBootApplication` annotation, it's not `@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"src.main.java.com.springlearn.learnspringdb"})` but `@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.springlearn.learnspringdb"})` that you should mention. Source folder doesn't count in the path to a class.

Answer (score 1):

1. Do you have, somewhere, a class annotated `@SpringBootApplication` giving the main method?

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"my.packages"})
public class Application {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
   }
}
```

2. Also, I don't know if it makes a difference, but I'm calling the plugin that way, adding an `executable = true` configuration to it:

```xml
<execution>
    <id>executable-jar</id>
    <phase>install</phase>

    <goals>
        <goal>repackage</goal>
    </goals>

    <configuration>
       <executable>true</executable>
    </configuration>
</execution>
```

Comment: Thanks for inputs. Yes i had annotation with @Spring boot application also i tried with your solution of executable tag but still facing the same issue

Comment: sharing my complete code https://github.com/algouser/learnspringdb